# My mesh goes nuts when I try to move points

Tags: mesh, origin, select

In edit mode I select a row of edges (alt+click), when I try to move the row with "G" it pulls points that aren't selected. I have tried to fix this any way I know how. (Including changing the origin of my object. I am getting ready to yeet my computer out the window. Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I transform faces, edges, or vertices without transforming the whole object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o) or [nearby objects wont move independently](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/nearby-objects-wont-move-independently/5199#5199) or [everything moves not just the selected-vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57323/everything-moves-not-just-the-selected-vertex/57324#57324)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have Proportional Editing enabled. Click on the O shaped icon and choose Disable, or just press the hotkey O (in blender 2.79) until the blue circle turns grey.

[image]